# How can we get another type of object while deserialization in DataContractSerializer?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, datacontractserializer, serializationbinder

In case of versioning of object, if the old version object is serialized and now I need deserialized object of new version.

I have checked over internet and observed that we can use [`SerializationBinder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder(v=vs.110).aspx) for that purpose. But I have no idea how can I use this with `DataContractSerialzer`.

This binder can be assigned to the `BinaryFormatter` using [`Binder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.binder(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Is anything similar present with the DataContractSerializer?

Please let me know if there is any other way to achieve this.

Please correct me, if I assumed anything wrong in this.

Comment: `DataContract`s have a powerful versioning system. You should read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-versioning) about it.

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] to answer the question.  One mechanism similar to `Binder` is [`DataContractResolver`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/youssefm/2009/06/05/configuring-known-types-dynamically-introducing-the-datacontractresolver/).  Another is the [data contract surrogate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/data-contract-surrogates).  Or make the new contract be [data contract equivalent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-equivalence) to the old, with the addition of some optional members.